# Why aren't these two strings the same, dictionary and input?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the code:

```
skill = input("Which skill would you like to increase by 1 ?: ")
            for x in abilities:
                if x.lower() == skill.lower():
                    abilities[x] += 1
                    break
            print("Sorry, I don't see that skill...")
```

and the dictionary being:

```
abilities = {
    "STR" : 10,
    "DEX" : 10,
    "CON" : 10,
    "INT" : 10,
    "WIS" : 10,
    "CHR" : 10 }
```

Then when for the input the string "STR" is put in, I get the response telling me the strings are not identical.

To my knowledge they are? Is there a really simple mistake here which I'm accidentally looking over, or is there a certain rule with this kind of thing?

Comment: it's better to 1) fix your indentation 2) avoid interactive reproducer: hardcode your input so it provides a [mcve].

Comment: Remember that in Python indentation is relevant and important. Therefore when you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you should make sure that it's actually correct (unless you're asking about syntax errors or exceptions from running it). And then you *copy-paste* it into the question body, without any modifications.

Comment: note that you're not using the dictionary "powers" at all. `collections.Counter()` would be really better for this.

Comment: please [edit] or delete your question. So far it attracted 2 guessed-wrong answers. Cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just when you thought that looking at python questions would be better than C questions ... :)

Comment: I'm willing to guess that the print is indented incorrectly. So OP is actually adding to `STR` but it's printing the message

Comment: @MooingRawr that's the bloody obvious but we didn't see it!

Comment: You're printing the message even if the value is updated. Use a variable, or see @Mureinik's answer for a better solution overall.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I still don't think you should use collections.Counter() here. You should `sum` up all the attribute and put it in a dictionary :D

Comment: aah yes, you're right (that old joke never gets old). And you also solved the mystery of that question. Thumbs up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in abilities:
    if x.lower() == skill.lower():
        abilities[x] += 1
        break
print("Sorry, I don't see that skill...")
```

that will print the error message regardless of the loop outcome.

Just add a `else` to your `for` loop and it will work

```
for x in abilities:
    if x.lower() == skill.lower():
        abilities[x] += 1
        break
else:
    # called when for loop ended without hitting break or return
    print("Sorry, I don't see that skill...")
```

however this is a very inefficient way of counting, you're not using the dictionary as it is, but just as a list of `tuples`, so linear search, highly inefficient

Use (without a loop):

```
skill = skill.upper()  # so casing matches the keys
if skill in abilities:
  abilities[x] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You know that `abilities`' keys are all upper-case strings, so you should convert the input to uppercase too:

```
skill = input("Which skill would you like to increase by 1 ?: ").upper()
if skill in abilities:
    abilities[x] += 1
else:
    print("Sorry, I don't see that skill...")
```